# How to make the input of a user open a file that matches the input on R

Tags: html, r, loops, file, character

How can I make it so that if a user enters a certain character sequence (i.e. a date like 20210721) and it matches the date that is on a certain file name (i.e. filename20210721.html), it opens that file for them on R?

I currently have a huge list of files that are essentially in HTML that are associated with different dates and am trying to make it so that if a user wanted to access a file from a particular date, all they would have to do is type/select that date and, as a result, the associated HTML file would open up.

That being said, I am not particular sure how to go about this and can share some sample code if you would like! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "it opens that file for them on R," what do you mean? Do you mean storing it as an object in the global environment?

Comment: I have a server that has thousands of HTML files on it! I want to make it so that when a certain date is entered, that particular "date" file is accessed, so no not storing it as an object but simply just opening the file associated with the date entered.

Comment: Do you mean open it in an IDE (e.g. RStudio)? Do you want it to be rendered as html or displayed as plain text that can be edited?

Comment: As long as the input given matches the file name, yes that is exactly what I want!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the rendering of it. I don't imagine it will need to be edited as long as the input aspect points to the correct file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
x <- readline(prompt = "Enter a date: ")
fl <- list.files(pattern = x)
viewer <- getOption("viewer")
viewer(fl)
```

---

### Edit

The following will open a tab per URL in `flnames`.
# this is only needed once
viewer <- getOption("viewer")

```
x <- readline(prompt = "Enter a date:")
flnames <- list.files(pattern = x)
for(u in flnames){
  viewer(u)
}
```

Comment: This only works if there are no duplicate dates! Is it possible to display both (if there are 2 for example) as I am getting this error: "url must be a single element character vector."

Comment: @NathanDrake You can loop through the string. See now.